# In a structural VHDL ROM, how can I have multiple word lines drive outputs?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, synthesis

I'm writing a ROM in structural VHDL for a class of mine. The design takes a 6-bit address and runs it through a 6-to-64 binary decoder. Each decoder output enables or disables a single 6 bit word line made of tri-state inverters. The word line bit inputs are either '1' or '0' for each bit. Most importantly, every word line writes to the *same* output vector.

When I check the syntax in Xilinx 9.2 it is fine, but when I synthesize I get this error:

```
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <ufm6bit> on signal <N0>
Sources are: 
   Output signal of BUFT instance <rom/word63rom/tri0/Z>
   Output signal of BUFT instance <rom/word62rom/tri0/Z> 
   Output signal of BUFT instance <rom/word...rom/tri0/Z> 
   Output signal of BUFT instance <rom/word00rom/tri0/Z>
```

I used a program to write the decoder VHDL so the port map is too big to put here (will put it on pastebin if you want). The word line looks like this:

```
entity tribuffer6 is
  PORT (
    A : in  std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    E : in  std_logic;
    Z : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0));
end tribuffer6;
```

and the 6 tribuffers it uses look like this:

```
entity tribuffer is
  Port ( A : in  std_logic;
         E : in  std_logic;
         Z : out std_logic);
end tribuffer;

architecture Behav of tribuffer is
begin

  z <= not a after 120 ps when e = '1' else
         'Z' after 120 ps;

end Behav;
```

finally the wordlines are tied up like this:

```
SIGNAL dataline : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);

word00rom : tribuffer6 PORT MAP (
                         A=>"000000",
                         Z=>dataline,
                         E=>word00en );
word01rom : tribuffer6 PORT MAP (
                         A=>"000000",
                         Z=>dataline,
                         E=>word01en );
```

It's obvious from the error that VHDL is not happy with having multiple drivers on that line, but there's no way I'm making 64 buffer vectors and chaining them together to defeat the checking. Nor would an OR tree 64-layers deep be practical. What do I have to do to get VHDL to be OK with this?

Update:
I should clarify a few things. The Xilinx 9.2 is a requirement for the class since it is free and my University is cheap. The only fundamental gates (and,or,not,nand,tristate) can be behavioral, everything else has to be structural. And it was the ROM that I generated the VHDL for, in C, because that would have been a lot of typing otherwise.

Comment: it looks like you actually are driving some kind of internal signal with multiple sources, however, it is in your generated code. You say your decoder is generated with a program: why? I am sure you can do it with generate statements or similar, also the signed and unsigned packages are very helpful: try something like word_enable <= (others => '0'); word_enable(conv_integer(adr)) <= '1';

Comment: Are you trying to synthesise a model of a tristate buffer? Try removing the `after 120ps` from your model.

Comment: What device are you targetting? Xilinx 9.2 - that's pretty old!

Comment: I should clarify a few things. The Xilinx 9.2 is a requirement for the class since it is free and my University is cheap. The only fundamental gates (and,or,not,nand,tristate) can be behavioral, everything else has to be structural. And it was the ROM that I generated the VHDL for, in C, because that would have been a lot of typing otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hoping to synthesize this, then you'd better just write the code for the OR-tree.

No (current) devices I'm aware of will be happy with internal tristates.  Either the synthesizer will choke (as yours appears to), or convert it (more or less silently) into a tree of muxes for you.

See this thread:

http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Spartan-Family-FPGAs/What-is-BUFT-in-this-RTL/td-p/111838

Comment: Could you elaborate on this tree of muxes vs. an OR tree? Is there an advantage to using muxes (which I imagine would incur a higher time delay and larger size), does it cause less line jitter?

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using std_logic_vector as opposed to std_ulogic_vector, it is legal for multiple sources to drive the "dataline" signal. It is valid VHDL and should work fine in simulation. I would guess that's enough to get the assignment approved.

FPGAs generally do not have internal tristate buffers. That is, there is no concept of the value 'Z' inside the FPGA you are trying to synthesize for. (They usually have tristate buffers on the pins, however, so it is possible to drive an output pin to 'Z'.) That's why your synthesis fails. If you have access to a synthesis tool for ASICs (such as Synopsys Design Compiler) you can try with that, which will most likely work.

Also note that explicit delays (wait for, after) are not synthesizable, neither for FPGAs nor ASICs.

Comment: internal tristate buffers will automatically be resolved to multiplexed structures in xilinx and altera tools with default settings...

Comment: You're right! My apologies, that does seem to work. I guess it should be possible to synthesize this after all. Perhaps the delays are causing the errors.

Comment: well obviously no timing constraint should appear in code that's supposed to be synthesized, but apart from that I would hazard a guess that multiple source signals are identified in a static analysis, i.e., no timing is involved anyway. I am quite sure that the problem is in the address decoder, and I am also sure that it should be possible to reduce it to something very small and debuggable....